# Document.createProcessingInstruction() on Edge / IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom, microsoft-edge, notsupportedexception

I'm currently working on a project which, in one use case, uses document.createProcessingInstruction method to create instruction nodes to the DOM.

I'm I missing something or what, but it seems that this method is not correctly implemented nor IE or Edge? (Tried to look information from the internet but to be honest, did not find any...)

If I make the following call

`document.createProcessingInstruction("a", "b")`

in Chrome developer tools console it works, but if I make same call in IE 11 or Edge it just throws NotSupportedError. Ok, NotSupportedError tells me that they have implemented it but still can't understand what happens.

Comment: Needs context. That line works just fine on its own in a script or in the F12 console.

Comment: Did you try it in Edge or IE11? Because for me it only throws NotSupportedError on both in any page...

Comment: I tried it in Edge, and it did not throw. Just tried it in IE11 and it does throw.

Comment: Ok.. It might be that our company is just stuck with some older version of Edge. Will try this at home and confirm your finding. Thanks!

Comment: Ok as I thought, our company is using Edge 38 which throws NotSupportedError when calling createProcessingInstruction. With 41 method is working!

Comment: @Quutti would you post that as an answer and accept it please?